# Perl regex: look for keyword which are not starting with

Tags: regex, perl

Example 1: `"hello this is me. KEYWORD: blah"`
Example 2: `"KEYWORD: apple"`

I just want to be able to catch `KEYWORD` in example 1, not 2 since in 2, it starts with `KEYWORD`

```
if ($line =~/KEYWORD:/x) {
    # do something
}
```

The above code catch both examples. How can I change regex so that it only catches `KEYWORD` in example 1?

PS Eventually I want example 1 to be `KEYWORD: blah`

Comment: What's the difference between example 2 and the _PS: Eventually I want example 1 to be `KEYWORD: blah`_ (except for "apple" vs. "blah")?

Comment: I agree with @PerlDog, your final comment *"PS Eventually I want example 1 to be KEYWORD: blah"* is rather cryptic. Perhaps what you're looking for is `s/.+(?=KEYWORD)//`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking for a keyword, you should be using `index` and not a regex :

```
if (index($line, 'KEYWORD') > 0) {
    # do something
}
```

See [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/) : `index STR, SUBSTR` returns `-1` if `SUBSTR` isn't found in `STR`, otherwise it return the index of `SUBSTR` in `STR` (starting at 0).

If you want to look for a more complex pattern than a simple keyword, then you should do as [@Perl Dog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284667/perl-regex-look-for-keyword-which-are-not-starting-with/38284817#38284817) said in his answer.

Comment: Very nice! I never think of `index()` but for simple cases (like this one) it is better, easier to read, and faster if that's an issue here.

Comment: If anyone thinks that `index($line, 'KEYWORD') > 0` is easier to read than something like `$line =~ /KEYWORD/ and $-[0] > 0` or my own solution then yeah, I guess, go ahead and use it. But please think of all the people following you who will have to read up on `index` to discover what your call is trying to do. And `index` is *not* faster than the equivalent regex match.

Comment: About the speed : you're right, it's not faster. But about the use of `index`, it's a standard Perl function, and people reading my code should know Perl, including `index`. About the readability, even your answer is confusing at first because it looks like you try to match `KEYWORD` but not `KEYWORD`... So I don't think there is a perfect answer, and any of PerlDog's/yours/mine look fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a *[negative lookbehind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)*, i.e. for 'KEYWORD' that is *not* preceeded by a certain string (in your case the start-of-line marker `^`):

```
if ($line =~/(?<!^)KEYWORD:/x) {
    # found KEYWORD in '$line', but not at the beginning
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hello this is me. KEYWORD: blah
```

---

**Update:** As stated in the comments, the `/x` modifier isn't necessary in my first regex but can be used to make the pattern more readable. It allows for whitespace (including newlines) and/or comments in the pattern to improve readability. The downside is that every blank/space character in the actual pattern has to be escaped (to distinguish it from the comments) but we don't have these here. The pattern can thus be re-written as follows (the result is the same):

```
if ($line =~ / (?<!       # huh? (?) ahh, look left (<) for something
                          # NOT (!) appearing on the left.
                ^)        # oh, ok, I got it, there must be no '^' on the left
                KEYWORD:  # but the string 'KEYWORD:' should come then
             /x ) {
    # found KEYWORD in '$line', but not at the beginning
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Since `^` and lookarounds are zero-width assertions, you can use a lookahead here: `/(?!^)KEYWORD:/` *(no need to put an x modifier, there aren't white-spaces nor comments)*.

Comment: Once again, too much crammed into a single regex pattern. I so often see people write code where once a regex has been used at all, it must provide the intelligence for *all of the rest of the program*. You have Perl at your disposal and you want to check whether `$_` *contains* `KEYWORD` but doesn't start with it. So write that: `if ( /KEYWORD/ and not /^KEYWORD/ ) { ... }`. I would rather not stare at your `(?<!^)` and wonder what it does. You even use the `/x` modifier and could have written `(?<!  ^  )` which would have helped

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's a nice alternative. I have to admit that these lookarounds are not as easy to read (and write) as Borodin's suggestion. // Yes, the /x is not necessary, I just copied it from the OP.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I would recommend the `/x` modifier, and that the opportunity is taken to expand `(?<!^)` or `(?!^) `which are otherwise just strings of punctuation. The point is that there *should be* whitespace layout and there is none

Comment: @Borodin I just updated my answer and made heavy use of the `/x` modifier. Thank you for your proposal.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually quite simple!

```
/.KEYWORD/    # Not at the start of a line
/.KEYWORD/s   # Not at the start of the string
```

By the way, you might want to add `\b` before `KEYWORD` to avoid matching `NOTTHEKEYWORD`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give better, real examples

On the face of it, all you need is

```
if ( /KEYWORD/ and not /^KEYWORD/ ) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple regex

```
print if /^.+KEYWORD/;
```

match

```
hello this is me. KEYWORD: blah
```